# Auto-Py-To-Exe Not able to run

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I am trying to run Auto Py To Exe, Without luck.
Getting this error message:

`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>auto-py-to-exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\michi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\auto-py-to-exe.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import ui
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\ui.py", line 5, in <module>
    import eel
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gevent.threading import Timer
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
    from gevent._hub_local import get_hub
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_hub_local.py", line 101, in <module>
    import_c_accel(globals(), 'gevent.__hub_local')
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_util.py", line 148, in import_c_accel
    mod = importlib.import_module(cname)
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "src\gevent\_hub_local.py", line 1, in init gevent._gevent_c_hub_local
  File "c:\users\michi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\greenlet\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ._greenlet import _C_API # pylint:disable=no-name-in-module
ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
```

`

So my question is how can i run Auto Py To Exe, Whithout a Error message?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem today. Then I debugged auto-py-to-exe a little bit and able to solve this issue. The main reason of this error is using latest version of some modules/package. To ease your suffering, I managed to solve this problem by executing one line of code.

```
pip uninstall auto-py-to-exe eel bottle gevent greenlet -y && pip install auto-py-to-exe==2.13.0 Eel==0.12.4 bottle==0.12.19 gevent==21.12.0
```

**Just execute this command and wait until it finishes**.

### What does this command do?

This command uninstalls latest version of `auto-py-to-exe` and other required package for `auto-py-to-exe` such as `eel` `bottle` `gevent` and `greenlet`. Then it install specific older version of these modules/packages. I hope you understood this.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command resolved the issue for me:

```
pip install msvc-runtime
```

Source: [an issue with import error dll load](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/10auyay/an_issue_with_importerror_dll_load_failed_while/) Reddit thread.